# move all items in 1 layer to top-most layer-tier in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, layers

In Illustrator, how do I move all vectors in 1 layer to top-most layer-tier and discard the sublayer containers and retain the original layer name?

Basically, bring all sublayers and contents to the top in 1 layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware there's no *one* solution which works for *everything* all the time.

Copy/Paste to a new layer is a good solution.

There are also some little used *Layer Panel menu items* that may help.

Note that **no** artwork is selected in this animation. It's *all* merely moving layers and layer structure.

Three layers, with nested sublayers on a couple of the layers.

- Highlight top layers and choose **Flatten Artwork** from the **Layer Panel Menu** -- This moves all layers, sublayers, and objects to *one* single layer. This is **not** like Photoshop's "Flatten" command. This ONLY refers to the layer structure in the panel and has *nothing* to do with actual artwork.
- Highlight sublayers and choose **Merge Selected** from the **Layer Panel Menu** -- this moves all sublayers to *one* sublayer.
- Highlight and Manually move objects out of that last sublayer.

[image]

How useful this is depends a great deal upon the current structure of any layers.

Depending upon how deep nested sublayers go, or how prolific they may be, it may take using the commands a few times on different sets of highlighted layers/sublayers.

Although I have all the layers/sublayers expanded for the animation, these commands work on collapsed layers. So, you don't *have* to expand layers, just highlight them and and choose the menu items.

Comment: Thank you so much. That's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Unlock all layers you want to move from.

Select All (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)

Cut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>)

Click on topmost layer, and paste-in-place* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>)

Now select extra layers and drag them to the trashcan.

[image: layers panel]

---

<sub>* Make sure you have *Paste Remembers Layers* turned **off**. Otherwise it'll recreate the sublayers etc. (Click on the dropdown in the layers panel to turn it off.)</sub>

Comment: That is a workaround yes. In cases with 100-500 vectors, It gets very time consuming to go through so many sublayers with just collapsing down. I meant is there a way to easily remove that hierarchy.

Comment: If they are all sublayers, just delete the second-main layer and all sublayers will be deleted too (see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGcfj.png))...

Comment: Also, I'd prefer using "ctrl+F" to paste in place. But I guess you know that.